# How to debug C++/C programs on VsCode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw, msys

I am using the gcc/g++ compiler using msys64 and mingw64 with VsCode. I've attached the bash.exe of mingw64 to my VsCode terminal. I can run my programs on the bash terminal using `g++ file_name.cpp && ./a.exe`.
But how do I debug my programs?

Comment: Follow the steps in the VSC C++ docs to the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually debugging in VScode is a bit tricky. Have you followed the methods here-

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug